# Database Updated_at Column not updated

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

In my Laravel Project im using the yajra library to handle Oracle database access.

I've got a table that uses a column with BLOB as datatype. When I try to update the BLOB with the following call, the "UPDATED_AT" column is not updated.

MyModel looks like this:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
     protected $connection = 'SECRET';
     protected $table = 'SECRET';
     protected $primaryKey = 'id';
     protected $fillable = [ 'myColumn', 'myColumn2'];
     
     protected $binaries = [
         'myBlob',
     ];
}
```

Thats mydatabase call:

```
$myModel = new MyModel();
$nonLobs = ['myColumn' => 'Some Value'];

// if i do this, its updated:
// $nonblobs['updated_at'] = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

$blobs = ['myBlob' => json_encode($notRelevant); // some blob.
DB::table($myModel->getTable())->where('id', 123)->updateLob($nonblobs, $blobs, 'id');
```

Is there a way to tell the updateLob() function to update the "UPDATED_AT" columns?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with `updateLob()`, you are using the query builder with `DB::table()`, `created_at` and `updated_at` belong to Eloquent, they are not touched when using the query builder.

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. Thanks :)